# perform search for the right datatype

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate

new to programming ,i'm building a webpage using MVC.net nhibernate,in my controller i'm using FormCollection fm object and jquery datatable. my problem is that i have a text box search which should search for data inside my data table as attached in the photo, i'm able to search for any string but i cant search for amount or date,someone asked me to use Tryparse but i don't understand why do i need it and what should i parse exactly?it has an if and else i have no idea what to write in them i attached also some of the code that can search for string as below :

[image]

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fm["SearchValue"]) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(fm["SearchType"]))
                         {
                             criteria.Add(Restrictions.Like(fm["SearchType"], "%" + fm["MobileNo"] + "%"));
```

i have tried this with amount but it never worked :

```
string SearchValue = fm["SearchValue"];
                       decimal Amount; 
                       if (decimal.TryParse(SearchValue, out Amount))
                       criteria.Add(Restrictions.Eq(fm["SearchValue"], Amount));
```

i have done this for both date and decimal but it wont work any idea what went wrong?i feel its inside the if not sure

```
 decimal Amount;
                             if (decimal.TryParse(fm["SearchValue"], out Amount))
                             {
                                 criteria.Add(Restrictions.Eq(fm["SearchValue"], Amount));

                             }



                            DateTime TransactionDate;
                             if (DateTime.TryParseExact(fm["SearchValue"], "dd MM yyyy HH:mm:ss", new CultureInfo("en-US"), DateTimeStyles.None,
                                out TransactionDate))

                            {
                                criteria.Add(Restrictions.Like(fm["SearchType"], "%" + TransactionDate + "%"));

                            }
```

Comment: I think `TryParse` has been suggested as a means of checking the datatype of the parameter. So if `DateTime.TryParse(SearchValue)` is true then you know it's a datetime parameter and you can use it to filter your data accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

TryParse does indeed parse the string, and only returns true if it is of the correct type:

```
DateTime date;
if (DateTime.TryParse(fm["SearchValue"], out date))
{
    // criteria.Add
}
```

The `out date` part of this allows the function to output the parsed `DateTime` so you can then work with it.

Please note, this may have undesired effects if you're only expecting the dates to be in certain formats. For example, this command will use the default locale settings, and might switch between DD/MM/YYYY and MM/DD/YYYY based on that.

If you know the date format you are expecting for this, you can use TryParseExact instead:

```
DateTime date;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(fm["SearchValue"],
    @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", // or any other DateTime format string
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
    DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal, 
    out date)
{
    // criteria.Add
}
```

You can `TryParse` many types in this way, for example:

```
if (int.Parse(value, out integer))
```

The DateTime example is probably the most complicated due to the vast number of ways a valid date/time can be entered.

---

**EDIT**:

If you're having trouble working out exactly what is going wrong, it can be easier to add a Console project to your solution and test the code from there. That way you can quickly and easily test a lot of different string values against your code and work out exactly which are working or not - or indeed determine if the entire TryParse is not working for you.

---

**EDIT 2:**

The code itself looks fine, so that leaves 2 possibilities

1) It could be that `fm["SearchValue"]` is null or not a valid decimal.
2) The alternative is that `criteria.Add(Restrictions.Eq(fm["SearchValue"], Amount));` is not valid for some reason - There could be any number of problems here.

Often when debugging web apps it can be hard to simply get the thing to stop and give you some info. Assuming you have debug mode on in the `web.config`, I find an easy way to check this is to add `throw new Exception("THIS WORKED!");` inside the if, like this:

```
decimal dec;
if (decimal.TryParse(fm["SearchValue"], out dec))
{
    throw new Exception("THIS WORKED!");
}
```

That way you'll at least know if `decimal.TryParse` is succeeding. If you see that message, you can focus your attention on the criteria.add line.

If you DON'T see the message, you know that `decimal.TryParse` is returning false, i.e. the contents of `fm["SearchValue"]` are not a valid decimal. At that point you can use the same trick again to double check what the value is, like this:

```
throw new Exception("!" + fm["SearchValue"] + "!");
```

Note - I've added characters around the value so you can more easily see if the value is simply a blank string.

Normally you never throw a raw Exception like that, but it is a very quick and easy way of getting a bit of debug data back at any stage in the page lifecycle in MVC.

Comment: that made sense but what about amount?i've used the above decimal.try parce but it wouldnt work..am i using it right?what should i write in else ?still confused here

Comment: The `TryParse` part of your code looks fine - are you sure the line inside the if statement is valid? Are you sure you're actually entering a valid decimal? Some of the examples on the [MSDN Page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9zbda557%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) might help you.

Comment: Oktopoid you helped much i appreciate i'll vote your answer but can you please take a look at my last edit, both are still not working date and amount (decimal)

Comment: Updated the answer - it'll almost certainly be one of those two :)